# using SMOTE to treat imbalanced 3d array data

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, imbalanced-data, smote

I have below data and here is the distribution of the classes.

```
X shape == (477324, 5, 11)
Y shape == (477324,)
{0: 11986, 1: 465338}
```

Since my dataset is imbalanced, I have tried RandomOverSampling using below code.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
oversample = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='minority')
oversample.fit_resample(trainX[:,:,0], trainY)
Xo = trainX[oversample.sample_indices_]
yo = trainY[oversample.sample_indices_]

Xo shape == (930676, 5, 11).
yo shape == (930676,).
{0: 465338, 1: 465338}
```

However, how can I use SMOTE on the same instead of RandomOverSampler?
I tried below code to apply SMOTE and reshaped it to 3d array as I need a 3d array after resampling too.

```
Xo_smote,yo_smote = oversample_Smote.fit_resample(trainX[:,:,0], trainY)

Xo shape == (930676, 5).
yo shape == (930676,).

org_shape= trainX.shape
Xo = np.reshape(Xo, org_shape)
```

and I get error `"ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51187180 into shape (477324,5,11)"` Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reshape the oversampled array, which due to the oversampling is now bigger than the original array, back into the original shape.

Here a minimum working example on how it would work with your given shapes:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
import numpy as np

train_features = np.random.rand(477324, 5, 11)
train_labels = np.array([0] * 11986 + [1] * 465338)
np.random.shuffle(train_labels)
print(train_features.shape, train_labels.shape)  # (477324, 5, 11) (477324,)

train_features_shape = train_features.shape
train_features = train_features.reshape(train_features.shape[0], train_features.shape[1]*train_features.shape[2])
print(train_features.shape, train_labels.shape)  # (477324, 55) (477324,)

sm = SMOTE(random_state=69)
train_features, train_labels = sm.fit_resample(train_features, train_labels)
print(train_features.shape, train_labels.shape)  # (930676, 55) (930676,)

train_features = train_features.reshape(train_features.shape[0], train_features_shape[1], train_features_shape[2])
print(train_features.shape, train_labels.shape)  # (930676, 5, 11) (930676,)
```